# Large MySQL Table daily updates?

Tags: mysql, compare

I have a MySQL table that has a bunch of product pricing information on around 2 million products. Every day I have to update this information for any products whose pricing information has changed [huge pain].

I am wondering what the best way to handle these changes are other than running something like `compare and update` any products that have changed ?

Love any advice that you can provide

Comment: It depends entirely on how you are detecting/tracking changes to the products.

Comment: well thats part of the problem to be honest - i'm unsure. i don't care about historical pricing info - only about bulk updating existing information on a live table [or sure perhaps through some temporary clone, compare and update or something]

Comment: But how are you picking up changes? Where are they coming from? What are the unique identifiers? What are your table structures?

Comment: Is there a timestamp of row changes somewhere? I'm not sure if you are supposed to copy a intranet database product information to a live database or to do something else. I'd imagine it would be possible to do something like `UPDATE products WHERE changed_time > yesterday` (whatever is the syntax for yesterday).

Comment: Do all the CSV files have the same structure? Approx how many records per file? Is it a mix of updates and inserts or just updates? How are you doing it currently?

Comment: Do the CSV files contain all records every day? Is there anything in the record to indicate whether it is new and/or updated? I would certainly load the CSVs into a temporary table as suggested by @BobbyW. The way the data is then synchronised to the main production tables would depend on the structure of the imported records. It would help if you posted the structure of the CSV files.

Answer (score 3):

For bulk updates you should definitely be using `LOAD DATA INFILE` rather than a lot of smaller update statements.

First, load the new data into a temporary table:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'foo.txt' INTO TABLE bar (productid, info);
```

Then run the update:

```
UPDATE products, bar SET products.info = bar.info WHERE products.productid = bar.productid;
```

If you also want to `INSERT` new records from the same file that you're updating from, you can  `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` all of the records that don't have a matching ID in the existing table then load that outfile into your products table using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Answer (score 2):

I maintain a price comparison engine with millions of prices and I select each row that I find in the source and update each row individually.  If there is no row then I insert.  Its best to use InnoDB transactions to speed this up.

This is all done by a PHP script that knows how to parse the source files and update the tables.